# Faking a Database record for Active Record methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using a find_by on an association:

"sub" has a many to one relation to "main"

```
@main.subs.find_by(x: 123)
```

in most cases I want this to access and retrieve from the database a "sub" record related to "main", using a regular select:

```
select subs.* from subs where subs.main_id = 333 and subs.x = 123
```

but there's another scenario, in which I want it to ignore the database and access a stub I've created of "subs" under "main":

```
stub_sub = Sub.new(id: 22, x: 123, main_id: 333)
@main.subs << stub_sub
```

@main isn't saved in the database either and is created just like the sub:

```
@main = Main.new(id: 333)
```

when I get to the find_by line while debugging, and try and access @main.subs, it looks just like an active record relation I'd get from a db query, but if I do something like find_by/all it will try to access the db and see there's nothing there and return an empty relation.

is there any way to prevent find_by (or any active record method) from accessing the database and just work on the stub relation I've created for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few misunderstandings in your question there. Firstly, the `find_by` method does not return *all* matching records but **just the [first one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)**, you probably wanted to use the `where` method instead.

Secondly, the `<<` operator on a `has_many` association actually [saves the association record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference-when-are-objects-saved-questionmark) so **a `where` query should return it perfectly after assigning the association**, i.e. just after calling `<<`.

**Update:** If the main object does not yet exist in the database either, then indeed the `<<` operator does not save anything. In that case, the only solution that comes to my mind is to give up ActiveRecord methods (such as `find_by` or `where`) because they always try to query the db to get the information and to search for the matching associated record manually instead.

So instead of `@main.subs.where(x: 123)` you would do:

```
@main.subs.to_a.select { |sub| sub.x == 123 }
```

This way, you will load all attached associations first, including the newly attached and unsaved ones and then filter them using a ruby condition against their attributes.

The big disadvantage of this is however that when using this code with a *saved* record, you will always load **all its associated records**, not only those which match the condition. Thus, if you had a record with a lot of associated records, you'd be killing the performance of such filtering.

Comment: Updated the question based on the link you've provided.
From what I see there the subs would be saved if the main was a record in the db as well, but in my case it isn't.. I'm stubbing everything from scratch and want to imitate database records to retrieve from.

Comment: OK, updated the answer. Also, one more question: is this supposed to be used in tests?

Comment: No, I wish.. then I could just stub the find_by as well and be done with it.
I'll have to just condition the find_by and only run it if I'm not supposed to use the stub, as the majority of times it's supposed to retrieve records from the db as opposed to not, and instead use a sort of hardcoded record.